# connect with APNS gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195 show blank

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

For IOS APNS i am try to connecting

```
$fp = stream_socket_client(
            'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
            $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

but $fp show blank .how to resolve
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but handling response for `$fp` and printing may provide you some more details.

```
if ($this->fp) {
    echo 'Successfully connected to server of APNS';

} else {
    echo "Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL;
}
```